# Extracting a number from the element's ID

Tags: javascript

I have a click `event` whose's target `event.target` I can print to the console using `console.log(event.target);` and it prints like this:

```
<path id="menu_0_bookmark_path" class="menu_X_bookmark_path active" d="m 67.279762,121.61904 c 0,11.1503 -7.276043,6.26851 -7.276043,14.93006 V 84.199403 c 0.188988,7.370536 7.370537,3.685275 7.276043,14.55209 z"></path>
```

I can see that `event.target` has `id="menu_0_bookmark_path"` which was clicked. I need to (a) extract number `0` from here and (b) concatenate it in a way that I will be able to target the corresponding element with `id="menu_0"`.

So how do I extract the number? Is it possible to do it using regular expressions? I need this to work with IE11...

Comment: *"Is it possible to do it using regular expressions?"* For sure. `id.match(/\d+/)`.

Comment: Are you in control of this page? This way of relating two elements is really not that good a design.

Comment: @trincot Yes I am in control. What do you suggest?

Comment: @FelixKling This is a nice suggestion and it works like a charm. I wonder why my design is not okay as trincot says.?

Comment: Often you can solve such problems without giving elements an `id` attribute, and certainly without `id` attributes that have some logical information hidden in them and/or a sequential number. Of course, without seeing the context in which you need this, your actual HTML and process, I cannot really suggest something to do this in a more elegant way.

Comment: @trincot Could you point me to an article explaining something about this? Because I used a lot (!) of ID's structured with numbers...

Comment: I don't have a reference. But if you ask a question with all the related information, I will be glad to post an answer.

Comment: Tomorrow. Today. I go to sleep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will give you `menu_0`

```
var id = 'menu_' + event.target.id.split('_')[1]
```

You can use the variable id, to select the corresponding DOM node

In the above code, `event.target.id.split('_')[1]` extracts the number from the id